# Issue On Closing Bootstrap 3 Collapse By Outside Click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [**This Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/WUI1CevxjM) and let me know why the collapse close button click only works at first click? Basically what I would like to do is closing the `#collapseOne` incase of it is open

Here is the code that I am using to close the `#collapseOne`

```
$("#close").on("click",function(){
  $('#collapseOne').collapse()
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Apparently answering questions is bad. So here's a comment with your answer. Throw 'hide' as the parameter in collapse n you should be good to go. $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide'); Works on your demo.

Comment: @below9k Who told you that? If question is good and you answer the question (and it solves the problem) you should put it in the answer and not in the comment

Comment: I'm just being a negative Nancy. I answered a post where OP had a typo and a typo correction wasn't good enough for an answer I suppose. Can't lose rep with comments though! As long as I have 50 and can help people I don't mind really. 
RELEVANT: I'm not sure why a method called collapse() would not collapse stuff without being told redundantly to collapse. I avoid bootstrap js and would the css too if it wasn't so damn easy to use. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: @below9k This is a known pitfall; see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13636

Comment: @below9k, put your answer up..